# Windows Azure Active Directory authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

We need an authentication process for Windows Azure Active Directory where we can get an access token after authentication for a web site.

Can anybody describe a process and sample application to do it in a asp.net mvc 4.0 and C#?

We do not need a native application to do so we need a web based authentication process.

Comment: a quick check on Windows Azure AD product documentation would have shown you this: [Adding Sign-On to Your Web Application Using Windows Azure AD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151790.aspx)

Comment: we have implemented this process but after authentication we are getting user details like username etc not access token here. we need to get access token after authentication which will be used for calling a api in the application.

Comment: If you're referring to JWT, see: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/11/20/introducing-the-developer-preview-of-the-json-web-token-handler-for-the-microsoft-net-framework-4-5-2/

Comment: For anyone on VS 2013, please note: **this answer is only applicable to VS 2012 due to it's dependency on the Identity and Access Tools for Visual Studio 2012.** Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any such tool for VS 2013 at this time; at least not one I've found any documentation for yet... I'll post back if I'm able to find anything.

Comment: there's none for VS 2103. part of it has been baked in VS already...see: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/06/26/improved-windows-azure-active-directory-integration-with-asp-net-amp-visual-studio.aspx